# Source code of Groovy ASTNode

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I implemented some AST transformations that are applied at compile time and for logging purposes I would like to emit "source" code that reflects injected AST nodes. The `toString()`/`getText()` methods return quite unreadable structure that quickly becomes complicated for long expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is the AstNodeToScriptAdapter which can be [found here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-console/src/main/groovy/groovy/inspect/swingui/AstNodeToScriptAdapter.groovy)

Comment: That is what I was looking for, how did you find it? I had hard time browsing through the GroovyConsole code to understand how it works with AST

Comment: I remembered Hamlet D'Arcy or someone discussing it on the mailing list, so did a quick search of my gmail archive ;-)